# Spark foreach(keyValue), whether value cause memory blow up?

Tags: python, apache-spark, foreach, out-of-memory, rdd

After `groupByKey()`, I got my RDD is only one line, such as `(0, [a list of name])`
The use-case: write the list of name to an file on s3. because this RDD is only one line, I directly use `foreach()`

code is:

```
def write_to_s3(keyValue):
    lines = keyValue[1]
    tmp_file = ...
    with open(tmp_file, w+) as f:
        for line in lines:
            f.write(line + '\n')
    # upload tmp_file to s3
    # remove tmp_file

myRDD.foreach(write_to_s3)
```

My question is in the function `write_to_s3()`, `lines = keyValue[1]`, is it possible to cause memory blow up since lines(the list) is too large?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is in the function write_to_s3(), lines = keyValue[1], is it possible to cause memory blow up since lines(the list) is too large?

No, but `groupByKey` alone is likely to do it anyways. In other words, you code might fail if data for a key is to large.

Best option you have is to use `DataFrameWriter` with `partitionBy` and merge and output the result.

```
df_before_group_by_key.toDF(["key", "value"]).write.partitionBy("key").text("some_file")
```

If it is not possible try:

```
df_before_group_by_key.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(...).mapPartitions(write_to_s2)
```

where

```
def write_to_s3(iterator):
     ... # 1. check the first key
     ... # 2. open new file
     ... # 3. write until you encounter new one
     ... # 4. upload
     ... # 5. go back to 2, repeat until iterator is empty
```

Comment: Could you tell me the reason why it won't cause memory blow up since the lines(the list) is too large?